# FLTK - Using Input values in an if statement (const char*)

Tags: c++, fltk

Fairly new to programming, currently doing a project using FLTK and I want to have an Fl_Int_Input, and use that to create an if statement which depends on what the person types in, something along the lines of:

```
if(input->value()=='1'){do this;}

if(input->value()=='2'){do this;}

else{do this;}
```

However when I use 'value', which looking online seems to be the way to use char values in an if statement, an error occurs: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer

I think it is because the value is a const char* rather than char. The code runs when I use

```
if(input->value()=="1"){do this;}
```

But even if I input 1 nothing occurs

How should I go about using this input to create an if statement?

Like I said I'm pretty new to all of this so I don't know what other relevant information you might need to help, I will try to provide whatever information you might need, these are my includes:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

#include <FL/Fl.H>
#include <FL/Fl_Window.H>
#include <FL/Fl_Box.H>
#include <FL/Fl_Button.H>
#include <FL/Fl_Check_Button.H>
#include <FL/Fl_Double_Window.H>
#include <FL/Fl_Output.H>
#include <FL/Fl_Input.H>
#include <FL/Fl_Int_Input.H>
#include <FL/Fl_Timer.H>
```

Typing the code on here, one thing I notice is that the '1' turns a red colour, which doesn't occur on my code, maybe that is relevant?

Comment: Start here: [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/1889329).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to learn how strings in C work.  The reason `if(input->value()=="1")` doesn't work for you is because the `==` operator on `char*` values does a pointer comparison, not a string comparison.

A pointer to the memory allocated for your string is returned by `FL_Input::value()` but that is not the same memory location as the string literal `"1"`, which is stored somewhere in your program's memory segment.

To do C-style string comparison you would do this:

```
if( 0 == strcmp( input->value(), "1" ) )
```

The `strcmp` function is available when you include `<cstring>`.

Another way to do this (but not very nice) is to copy that value into a temporary `std::string` object and use its overloaded `operator==( const char *)`:

```
if( std::string( input->value() ) == "1" )
```

To use `std::string`, include `<string>`.

More reading:

- [strcmp](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp)
- [std::string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string)

Comment: Thank you for the very quick reply! Still getting my head around pointers so this was really helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing this is by saving the value in a variable then using the variable in the if statement.

```
std::string input_value;
input_data = input -> value();
if (input_data =="1") //should be in a callback or some function 
{ do this ...}
else if (input_data == "0")
{ do this ...}
else
{ do this ...}
```

Hope I understood and answered your question